# Nvidia driver is not recognized properly

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, nvidia-smi

OS:Ubuntu 20.04LTS
Windows10 dual boot

Error with nvidia-smi command after apt installation of nvidia driver.

```
$ nvidia-smi
Unable to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:0B:00.0: Not Found
```

```
$ dmesg |grep NVRM
[    3.065144] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX Open Kernel Module for x86_64  520.56.06  Release Build  (dvs-builder@U16-T12-10-2)  Thu Oct  6 21:33:54 UTC 2022
[    5.299612] NVRM: Open nvidia.ko is only ready for use on Data Center GPUs.
[    5.299614] NVRM: To force use of Open nvidia.ko on other GPUs, see the
[    5.299615] NVRM: 'OpenRmEnableUnsupportedGpus' kernel module parameter described
[    5.299616] NVRM: in the README.
[    5.692026] NVRM: GPU 0000:0b:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x63:0x0:1900)
[    5.692585] NVRM: GPU 0000:0b:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[   19.458670] NVRM: GPU 0000:0b:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x63:0x0:1900)
[   19.459831] NVRM: GPU 0000:0b:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
...
```

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver
ii  nvidia-driver-520-open                     520.56.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        NVIDIA driver (open kernel) metapackage
```

I have tried reboot, secure boot and driver reinstallation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [several](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/unable-to-determine-the-device-handle-for-gpu-000000-0-not-found/231923) [answers](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/unable-to-determine-the-device-handle-for-gpu-000000-0-not-found/231710) [given](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/unable-to-determine-the-device-handle-for-gpu-000000-0-not-found/231652) on the Nvidia developers forum, try installing the non-`open` version of the drivers.

I also recommend holding (with apt) the version of the drivers to avoid future mismatches.

Comment: Thank you, I will use a non-open version of the drivers.

Comment: @Martino, thank you! I've installed nvidia-driver-525-open with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and received "No devices found" when running `nvidia-smi`. Following your advice, I just installed 525 non-open and nvidia-smi is working!

Answer (score 0):

I lowered the version of nvidia-driver and it solved the problem.